# Как правильно поправить css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ситуация такая: когда водишь курсором по фону, он меняет свой угол, хочу поверх добавить текст и ссылки, если текст можно сделать некликабельным через pointer-events: none; то для ссылки это уже не подойдет. Нужно чтобы когда наводишь на ссылку и водишь по ссылке курсором, фон так же менял свой угол, а не замирал.

Пример есть [здесь](https://www.videinfra.com/), но я не могу понять, как они добились такого эффекта

P.S. Текст не должен менять угол

```js
$('.for-tilt').tilt({
 maxTilt: 10,
  perspective: 500,
  reset: false,
  scale: 1.2,
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.for-tilt {
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oZa_djYJr4E/maxresdefault.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="for-tilt"></div>
  <div class="content">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти, парадигматическая, живет!
      <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти, парадигматическая, живет!
      <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти, парадигматическая, живет!
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  
  
</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tilt.js/1.2.1/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, передать события перемещения мыши по одному элементу на другой:

```
$('a').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.for-tilt').trigger(e);
});
```

```js
$('.for-tilt').tilt({
  maxTilt: 10,
  perspective: 500,
  reset: false,
  scale: 1.2,
});

$('a').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.for-tilt').trigger(e);
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.for-tilt {
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oZa_djYJr4E/maxresdefault.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="for-tilt"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти, парадигматическая, живет!
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a> Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти,
    парадигматическая, живет!
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a> Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую заманивший инициал ipsum ему безорфографичный злых раз назад жаренные наш букв заголовок, пустился вопрос взобравшись маленькая! Власти,
    парадигматическая, живет!
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>


</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tilt.js/1.2.1/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

а на сайте, который вы указали для примера, это реализуется через стили + скрипт(`landing.js`), если проанализировать можно сделать так же:

```
<img class="pages__background__item background-cover cases-background" 
style=  'background-position: center; 
    background-image: url("https://www.videinfra.com/images/cases/loftec/background.jpg?deimt"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-origin: content-box; 
    background-size: cover; 
    transform: rotateX(6.88493deg) rotateY(-1.68438deg) translateZ(-15vw) scale(1.4);' 
draggable="false" 
alt="" 
src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1600' height='900'%3E%3C/svg%3E" 
data-ofi-src="https://www.videinfra.com/images/cases/loftec/background.jpg?deimt">
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел ответов нигде и написал нечто похожее с помощью друга.

```js
var mpHeight = $('.main-page').height();
var mpWidth = $('.main-page').width();

$('.main-page').mousemove(function() {
 var cX = event.clientX;
 var cY = event.clientY;
  
  if (cX < mpWidth/2) {
   cX = event.clientX - mpWidth/2;
  } else {
   cX = event.clientX - mpWidth/2;
  }
  
  if (cY < mpHeight/2) {
   cY = event.clientY - mpHeight/2;
  } else {
   cY = event.clientY - mpHeight/2;
  }
 
  $('.for-trans').css({
   "transform" : "scale(1.2) perspective(1000px) rotateX(" + cY/54  + "deg) rotateY(" + cX/46 + "deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
.main-page {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.some-content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
.for-trans {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://on-desktop.com/wps/Animals___Wild_cats_The_head_of_the_evil_lion__gray_background_100073_.jpg) 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="mp" class="main-page">
  <div class="for-trans"></div>
  <div class="some-content">
    <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Выйти lorem послушавшись первую эта семь своих, которое мир рекламных, там буквоград рыбного рукописи продолжил своего курсивных буквенных подзаголовок коварный.</p>
    <a href="#">ссылка</a>
    
    
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```